# Wicket : how to set checked value in CheckBoxMultipleChoice

Tags: java, checkbox, wicket

I am using wicket's CheckBoxMultipleChoice to let the user set a list of options. so far it works fine. but then i want to add a "check all" check box that checks all the options in the CheckBoxMultipleChoice and I am having problems with that.

here is my initial code

```
ArrayList<String> chosen;
List<String> choices = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Train", "Bus", "Car"});  
CheckBoxMultipleChoice myCheck = new CheckBoxMultipleChoice("transport", new Model(chosen), choices)); 
myCheck.setOutputMarkupId(true);
form.add(myCheck);
```

on submit i print out the values of chosen and its "Bus", "Car" etc. as expected.

now i am adding a checkbox to check all the choices using ajax:

```
Boolean checkOrNot;
final CheckBox checkAll = new CheckBox("checkAll", new Model(checkOrNot));  
form.add(checkAll);
checkAll.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {         
        // here i am not able to set the checkboxes 

        // i tried doing this
    chosen.clear();
    chosen.add(new String("Car"));
    chosen.add(new String("Train"));    
        myCheck.modelChanged();

        // i have also tried recreating the multiple choice     
        myCheck = new CheckBoxMultipleChoice<T>("transport", new Model(chosen), choices);

        myCheck.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        target.addComponent(myCgecj);
        target.addComponent(form);          
    }
});
```

I am running out of ideas and wondering if anyone has any solutions? thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Also I am wondering if a CheckGroup will be a better choice in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't (and can't) try that right now, so this is to be taken with a grain of salt, but couldn't you use a [CheckGroup](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/CheckGroup.html) for that?

From the JavaDoc:

Component used to connect instances of Check components into a group. Instances of Check have to be in the component hierarchy somewhere below the group component. The model of the CheckGroup component has to be an instance of java.util.Collection. The model collection of the group is filled with model objects of all selected Check components.

So a

```
new Checkgroup("group", choices)
```

should work for you. No need to reimplement that functionality.

P.S.: I'll check that as soon as I've got the chance to do so...

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript to mark the checkboxes.

An example, using jQuery:

```
mycheck.setOutputMarkupId(true);
checkAll.add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("onclick",
    "$('#" + mycheck.getMarkupId() + " input:checkbox').attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'))");
```

Comment: Thanks, javascript was the next thing I was going to try.

Answer (score 1):

Well, another way to go is to use

```
checkBoxMultipleChoice.setDefaultModelObject(listOfAllElements); // Select all.
checkBoxMultipleChoice.setDefaultModelObject(Lists.newArrayList()); // Deselect all.
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that you fount already an answer but in my case I had exactly the same issue, but the option to use the CheckGroup was not feasible because my list is built dynamically and at the beginning it can even be empty.

The situation for me was:

1. I was obliged to use the **CheckBoxMultipleChoice** because it allows me to have empty lists thus reflecting in the GUI. CheckGroups will always print one check box without label, even if the options for the component are empty.
2. Using **AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior** would throw an exception saying it was only possible to use it in other components.
3. Using **OnChangeAjaxBehavior** would work with the selector CheckBox (select/deselect) but if used with the CheckBoxMultipleChoice then the event will fire but the actual values of the component will not be reflected in the model within the event.

Thanks god I found [This Forum in Nabble](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/CheckboxMultipleChoice-doesn-t-support-Ajax-Behavior-td3095768.html).

Basically here Pedro Santos propose to use the **AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior** instead. I followed the advice and finally I was able to get the values in the model.

Sometimes I think Wicket is Wicked :P